# Is this some kind of morphism in the recursion-schemes?

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes, euclidean-algorithm

I implemented Euclid's algorithm in the following way at first.

```
euclid x 0 = x
euclid x y = euclid y (x `mod` y)
```

The algorithm is tail-recursion, and I expect that it can be intuitively written with [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes).
Then, the following *euc* is an extract of the recursive part.
This *euclid* function uses *euc*, while *psi* is devoted to one-step processing.

```
euc :: (a -> Either t a) -> a -> t
euc psi = either id (euc psi) . psi

euclid :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
euclid x y = euc psi (x, y)
  where psi (x, y) | m == 0    = Left  y
                   | otherwise = Right (y, m)
          where m = x `mod` y
```

The *euc* function looks like the [*apo*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.2.2.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:apo) morphism, but I don't know how to specialize *apo* to *euc*. It seems to me that they are completely different things.
Is it possible to write *euc* as some kind of morphism in recursion-schemes?

```
apo :: Functor f => (t -> f (Either (Fix f) t)) -> t -> Fix f
apo psi = In . fmap (uncurry either (id, apo psi)) . psi
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution using apomorphism:
Using the Delayed structure from @duplode would probably make this code better.

```hs
gcd' x y = cata alg $ apo coalg (x, y)
  where
    alg NilF = 0
    alg (ConsF a b) = a + b
    coalg (a, b) = case a `mod` b of
                     0 -> ConsF b (Left (Fix NilF))
                     m -> ConsF 0 $ Right (b, m)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can write it as an apomorphism, but I do see a way you can write it as a hylomorphism:

```
euc = hylo $ either id id
```

I also found a way to write it as an Elgot algebra:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
euc psi = elgot runIdentity (fmap Identity . psi)
```

Comment: It was a blind spot for me to get hylomorphism!
I haven't studied Elgot Algebra very well yet, and I didn't understand its merits, so I thought I'd better study it a bit.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

`Either` plays differents roles in your `euc` and in `apo`. You are using `Left` to signal a recursive base case, while `apo` uses `Left` to signal early termination of corecursion (that is, to add an extra condition for interrupting an unfold). If you want to express your algorithm using an unfold, though, there is no need for early termination, assuming an adequate structure to be unfolded:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

data Delayed a = Done a | Waiting (Delayed a)
    deriving (Show)
makeBaseFunctor ''Delayed
```

```
ghci> :info DelayedF
data DelayedF a r = DoneF a | WaitingF r
```

```
psi :: Integral i => (i, i) -> DelayedF i (i, i)
psi (x, y) = case x `mod` y of
    0 -> DoneF y
    m -> WaitingF (y, m)
```

`psi` is a coalgebra for `Delayed`, and `ana psi` unfolds a `Delayed` structure with the GCD at its end:

```
ghci> delayedGCD = ana psi (14,35) :: Delayed Integer
ghci> delayedGCD
Waiting (Waiting (Done 7))
```

To get the final result, we have to consume the `Delayed`:

```
ghci> cata (\case { DoneF n -> n; WaitingF n -> n }) delayedGCD
7
```

Given we are doing an `ana` followed by a `cata`, we'd better switch to `hylo`, which efficiently combines them:

```
ghci> hylo (\case { DoneF n -> n; WaitingF n -> n }) psi (14,35)
7
```

At this point, we might note that `DelayedF` is isomorphic to `Either`. Since for our current purposes we only need `hylo`, as opposed to `ana` or `cata` in isolation, it is actually possible to replace `DelayedF` with `Either` and skip defining `Delayed` altogether (note the type of `hylo` doesn't mention the implied recursive data structure, only its corresponding base functor):

```
euclid :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
euclid x y = hylo (either id id) psi (x, y)
    where
    psi :: Integral i => (i, i) -> Either i (i, i)
    psi (x, y) = case x `mod` y of
        0 -> Left y
        m -> Right (y, m)
```

```
ghci> euclid 14 35
7
```

And thus we reach [Joseph Sible's `hylo` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69716993/2751851), which works because `Either` is a base functor for a data structure that in some way materialises your recursive algorithm.

Comment: I notice that your `Delayed` type is isomorphic to `Free Identity`.

Comment: Also, since the generated `DelayedF` is isomorphic to `Either`, I wonder whether it'd be better to just do `type instance Base (Delayed a) = Either a` and then write the very simple `Recursive` and `Corecursive` instances by hand.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica (1) Good catch! Incidentally, that also means another way of trying it out without defining `Delayed` would be doing everything in terms of `Free`/`FreeF`. (2) Also a good point. While I'm inclined towards leaving the answer as it is, as it is perhaps closer to how we'd typically use *recursion-schemes* in practice, there's a reasonable case either way as far as presentation goes.

Comment: In fact, I was not sure about Left / Right.
In the original *euc*, it could be done either way, so I didn't have much of a basis for it. (In fact, I was rewriting the question and had it backwards at first).
Your explanation with Delayed is very clear and makes me think about its meaning.
Thank you very much for the very good explanation.

Comment: @いとうかつとし You're welcome :) And yes, as far as the original `euc` goes `Left` versus `Right` is largely a matter of convention, though once we use `Either` as the base functor the *recursion-schemes* machinery forces our hand, as it requires the position targeted by `fmap` to be the recursive one.

Comment: @duplode Actually, I prefered to use `type instance Base ...` like Joseph.
This is because I don't like the way TemplateHaskell hides things.
But it certainly should depends on the situation, not on my preference.

I only knew how to create a recursive type that is as the fixed point from a base functor, or how to have a recursive type first and then connect the base functor with `type instance Base ...`.
So I learned a lot from the way you showed me how to generate a base functor from a recursive type with makeBaseFunctor.